How to programatically get a list of all packages that can be upgraded?
I'd like to write a function that returns a list of packages that can be upgraded.

I know I can use list-package and then type U to search and list all packages that can be upgraded.
But this is an interactive method.  I want to get the list programmatically.

I wrote the following code that does it.  It uses package.el functions meant to be 'private', something I normally try to avoid doing:
(defun upgradable-packages ()
  "Return a list of elpa-compliant packages that can be upgraded."
  (require 'package)
  ;; create a temporary special buffer to use package-menu-mode                                                                                                                            
  (let ((upgradables nil)
        (buf  (get-buffer-create "*pel-package*")))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      ;; Since some packages have their descriptions include non-ASCII                                                                                                                     
      ;; characters...                                                                                                                                                                     
      (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
      (package-menu-mode)
      (when (fboundp 'package--ensure-package-menu-mode)
        (package--ensure-package-menu-mode))
      ;; Fetch the remote list of packages.                                                                                                                                                
      (package-refresh-contents)
      (package-menu--generate nil t)
      (setq upgradables (package-menu--find-upgrades)))
    ;; return a list of all keys; the names of packages that could be upgraded
    (mapcar 'car upgradables)))

Is there something else that does that already?  I could not find any.
Is there a problem with the above approach?

I don't know much about package.el but FWIW, this looks OK to me. It is regrettable that you have to do all the setup above (i.e. there should be an interface to simplify the setup - that would also give one confidence that the setup is complete) but calling a private function like package-menu--find-upgrades does not bother me much (until it is changed of course :-))

Thanks @NickD,  I updated it a little to make it compatible with Emacs 26. I also noticed that one of the public functions could be used.
